# Redirect http to https AWS ELB without hosting ssl certificate on webserver

Tags: redirect, ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb

I have web servers running nginx behind a AWS ELB. I have setup the ELB to accept https connections, and send the requests over http to the webservers. I would also like to accept http connection to the ELB, and redirect them to https.

All solutions to this redirection problem involve handling https on the webserver and redirecting it to http.

Is there a way to do this without handling the redirect on the webserver? I would rather not have to have my ssl certificate on the ELB and all webservers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very common. It'll depend on what your webserver is, but you look for the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. If it's set to `http`, redirect the user.

[Here's Amazon's documentation on the X-Forwarded-* headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html), and [here's a blog entry talking about *one way* to implement the forward in nginx](http://scottwb.com/blog/2013/10/28/always-on-https-with-nginx-behind-an-elb/).

Comment: The only issue with the solution in the blog post is that I must specify my domain name in my nginx config, rather than just localhost